# MIcrosoft Outlook stopped working on Yosemite

Tags: ms-office, macos

I ran Outlook for a day after updating to Yosemite, but after a reboot, it no longer works.

When I click on the Outlook icon, it bounces a few times but never runs. Looking in system.log (via Console.app), it complains about a call to gestaltSystemVersion from both Outlook and Microsoft Database Daemon. (see below)

I rebooted again, and I reinstalled Office for Mac 2011. My Outlook is version 14.4.5. I've found very little regarding this error searching Google, and most of it is from the beta stage for Yosemite.

Has anyone else seen this, or better, solved it?

```
Nov 4 08:42:15 JLGPB Microsoft Outlook[1664]: objc[1664]: Class OnClickLinkAction is implemented in both /Applications/Microsoft Office 2011/Office/OutlookLegacy.framework/Versions/14/OutlookLegacy and /Applications/Microsoft Office 2011/Microsoft Outlook.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft Outlook. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined. 
Nov 4 08:42:15 JLGPB Microsoft Outlook[1664]: objc[1664]: Class ERExtraKeyedTableColumn is implemented in both /Applications/Microsoft Office 2011/Office/OutlookPaletteItems.framework/Versions/14/OutlookPaletteItems and /Applications/Microsoft Office 2011/Microsoft Outlook.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft Outlook. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined. 
Nov 4 08:42:15 JLGPB.local Microsoft Outlook[1664]: WARNING: The Gestalt selector gestaltSystemVersion is returning 10.9.0 instead of 10.10.0.
    Use NSProcessInfo's operatingSystemVersion property to get correct system version number.
    Call location: 
Nov 4 08:42:15 JLGPB.local Microsoft Outlook[1664]: 0 CarbonCore 0x9ba5e7e7 ___Gestalt_SystemVersion_block_invoke + 135 
Nov 4 08:42:15 JLGPB.local Microsoft Outlook[1664]: 1 libdispatch.dylib 0x9021c130 _dispatch_client_callout + 50 
Nov 4 08:42:15 JLGPB.local Microsoft Outlook[1664]: 2 libdispatch.dylib 0x9021c0b5 dispatch_once_f + 251 
Nov 4 08:42:15 JLGPB.local Microsoft Outlook[1664]: 3 libdispatch.dylib 0x9021d0d8 dispatch_once + 31 
Nov 4 08:42:15 JLGPB.local Microsoft Outlook[1664]: 4 CarbonCore 0x9b9f0fb8 _Gestalt_SystemVersion + 1050 
Nov 4 08:42:15 JLGPB.local Microsoft Outlook[1664]: 5 CarbonCore 0x9b9f0b69 Gestalt + 150 
Nov 4 08:42:15 JLGPB.local Microsoft Outlook[1664]: 6 OutlookCore 0x0180563b _ZN6carbon22HasSnowLeopardOrBetterEv + 45 
Nov 4 08:42:16 JLGPB.local Microsoft Database Daemon[1666]: WARNING: The Gestalt selector gestaltSystemVersion is returning 10.9.0 instead of 10.10.0.
    Use NSProcessInfo's operatingSystemVersion property to get correct system version number.
    Call location: 
Nov 4 08:42:16 JLGPB.local Microsoft Database Daemon[1666]: 0 CarbonCore 0x9ba5e7e7 ___Gestalt_SystemVersion_block_invoke + 135 
Nov 4 08:42:16 JLGPB.local Microsoft Database Daemon[1666]: 1 libdispatch.dylib 0x9021c0b5 dispatch_once_f + 251 
Nov 4 08:42:16 JLGPB.local Microsoft Database Daemon[1666]: 2 libdispatch.dylib 0x9021d0d8 dispatch_once + 31 
Nov 4 08:42:16 JLGPB.local Microsoft Database Daemon[1666]: 3 CarbonCore 0x9b9f0fb8 _Gestalt_SystemVersion + 1050 
Nov 4 08:42:16 JLGPB.local Microsoft Database Daemon[1666]: 4 CarbonCore 0x9b9f0b69 Gestalt + 150 
Nov 4 08:42:16 JLGPB.local Microsoft Database Daemon[1666]: 5 MicrosoftComponentPlugin 0x0035f3be McpInitLibrary_ + 505 
Nov 4 08:42:16 JLGPB.local Microsoft Database Daemon[1666]: 6 MicrosoftComponentPlugin 0x0035f1ee McpInitLibrary_ + 41
```

Comment: I don't think those errors are the cause of your crashes. I get them with Outlook running Yosemite and my Outlook operates fine. They are just warnings to developers to update their code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After to Alistair's comment, I did some more general googling. I found some suggestions that the [best solution was to rebuild the identity](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macoutlook/outlook-for-mac-does-not-work-on-os-x-1010/ffbd926a-cda9-4ba1-ac3c-8b829f40af78), so that's what I did:

1. go to ~/Documents/Microsoft User Data
2. make a "backup folder"
3. drag the contents of ~/Documents/Microsoft User Data/Office 2011
   Identities into the backup folder
4. relaunch Outlook and configure
   as if it's a fresh install.

This has things working again.

Comment: i love you mannnn <3

Answer (score 3):

Without more clues its hard to give specific advice, but this is what I would try.

### Clear out the Saved Application State

Look for Outlook's saved application state folder within your account. You should find it at `/Users/YOURUSERNAME/Library/Saved Application State/com.microsoft.Outlook.savedState`. Just rename or delete the folder. Then launch Outlook to see if it opens successfully.

### Hide your Outlook Identities folder

Rename the `/Users/YOURUSERNAME/Documents/Microsoft User Data/Office 2011 Identities' folder to something like`Office 2011 Identities Old`, and try Outlook again.

### Hide Outlook's preference list files

Within `/Users/YOURUSERNAME/Library/Preferences` you should find four Outlook plist files.

```
com.microsoft.outlook.database_daemon.plist
com.microsoft.outlook.databasedaemon.plist
com.microsoft.outlook.office_reminders.plist
com.microsoft.Outlook.plist
```

Rename them or drag them to another location temporarily, and try Outlook again.

There are also Outlook plist files in `/Library/Preferences/`. On my Mac they are blank, if they have content on your Mac you might want to try renaming or moving them temporarily and trying again.

### Hide Office's Cache folder

Temporarily rename the `/Users/YOURUSERNAME/Library/Caches/com.microsoft.Outlook` folder something like `com.microsoft.Outlook.old` and try Outlook again.

### Hide the Office Application Support folder

Similarly temporarily rename the `/Users/YOURUSERNAME/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Office` and try again.

### Still not working?

Try running `sudo opensnoop | grep Outlook` in a Terminal window and see if you can work out which files Outlook accesses before giving up and closing.

Comment: As noted in http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/154712/47159 I basically took your second step and that worked, so can't really do the rest. But these may help the next person who comes along.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the best action in order to get again my Outlook operative was:

- go to `~/Documents/Microsoft User Data`
- make a "backup folder" (just in case)
- drag the contents of `~/Documents/Microsoft User Data/Office 2011 Identities` into the backup folder
- relaunch Outlook and configure as if it's a fresh install.
- shut outlook before it keeps on downloading all server(s) messages
- completely erase (even from the Trash bin) all messages directly from the server(s). Close server once it is empty.
- relaunch outlook. It stops closing, and works fine in spite of heavy use I give to it on a daily manner.

I can then confirm that ONE email message awaiting in the server to be downloaded to  outlook  was corrupt (or something) making  outlook crash again and Again every time I relaunched it. I had had the problem almost two days and every other solution I tried was useless; it all started with a problem with the Microsoft Daemon Database close message to a general Microsoft Outlook has found a problem and will close message.

Answer (score 0):

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2360509

Microsoft suggests rebuilding the Identities database to attempt to correct this.

Navigate in finder  Home > Documents > Microsoft User Data > Office 2011 identities

A quick summary of the link above:

- Quit all applications
- Determine the amount of space available on the hard disk - you will need 3x the size of the Identities folder in free space on your disk
- Backup up the Identities folder somewhere
- Hold down the Option key while starting Outlook and in the Database Utility window that appears, select the database that you want to maintain, and then click Rebuild.
- Make a cup of tea while the database is rebuilt
- Once the Utility has announced "Done" launch Outlook as normal

Comment: While the linked page may answer the question, we prefer answers which include the relevant parts directly in the answer to avoid problems if the link breaks in the future.

Comment: OK good point  - will do :)